# How do I launch Pidgin when I click on an irc:// link?

Tags: irc, url, pidgin

Is there a way that when you click an IRC url (such as `irc://##linux`) that it will open Pidgin? I believe it has something to do with `gconf-editor`, but I do not know the terminal command to start an IRC chat in Pidgin.

I am using Linux Mint, if that matters.

Comment: Click an IRC URL where?  In a browser?  (Which one?)  In a terminal window?

Comment: Set up a URL handler?  See [How to setup URL handlers for Gnome applications](http://logicbomblabs.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/how-to-setup-url-handlers-for-gnome-applications/) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up to Mikel's answer, check out [Integrating a new URIs Scheme handler to Gnome and Firefox](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/). (Posted this because Mikel's link is now a dead link).